# Programmatically exclude one of multiple fields views

Tags: views, 8, hooks

I'm using `hook_views_pre_render` to change the output of a view. The view outputs an `entity_reference` field of a paragraph called `field_date`. This paragraph contains two date fields, a begin date and an end date (I'm not using the daterange module of drupal 8 core).

The `field_date` in the view is [hidden]. Multiple field settings is set to `display all values in same row` with a simple seperator. It is used in a `Custom text field` to output with other fields like so:

```
<a href="{{ path }}" class="card card__agenda col-4 month-{{ field_begin_datum_1 }}">
<div class="wrapper__image">
    <div class="wrapper__tags">
        <div class="tag date">{{ field_date }}</div>
        <div class="tag discipline">{{ field_discipline }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">{{ field_afbeelding }}</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper__text">
    <div class="title">{{ title }}</div>
    <div class="body">{{ field_korte_omschrijving }}</div>
    <div class="wrapper__tags">
        <div class="tag locatie">{{ field_event_locatie }}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The date output looks like this:

```
Wed, 01/17/2018 - 20:00
Wed, 01/17/2018 - 23:00,
Mon, 02/19/2018 - 20:00
Mon, 02/19/2018 - 21:00
```

With the code below I can read the target_id of a multi field entity_reference to a  paragraph.

```
foreach ($view->result as $i => $val) {
  $dateArray = $val->_entity->get('field_date')->getValue();
}
```

This code will output all `target_id` of the results the view gives. In one particular case the ouput is.

`target_id: 41`
`target_id: 52`

So two fields, with these ids I load the paragraph to see what values they have and find out I don't want to output the `target_id: 52` field, I only want to show the date in January so `target_id: 41`. How can I exclude it or hide it from this hook without changing the values for good?

My complete hook is:

```
function hook_views_pre_render($view) {
    if ($view->id() == "view_id" && $view->current_display == 'view_display') {
        /* CHECK IF DATE IS IN THIS MONTH ELSE DELETE */
        // Get a node storage object.
        $node_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('paragraph');
        $dateArray = $val->_entity->get('field_date')->getValue();
        foreach ($dateArray as $iDate => $valDate) {
            //Get target id
           $targetId = $valDate['target_id'];
           //Load target paragraph
           $targetParagraph = $node_storage->load($targetId);
           //Get this month
           $resultMonth = explode('-', $targetParagraph->get('field_begin_datum')->value)[1];
           //If result month is not same as group month, hide output
           if($resultMonth != $month){
               //don't output this paragraph
            }
            else{
               //output this paragraph
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a little more detail about your view ...  without this hook is the paragraph displayed ? how ?

Comment: Hello Giorgos, thanks for your reply, I updated my question with more detailed information about the view.